# How do I remove all the nonunique key value pairs after inverting a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a dictionary that contains nonunique key value pairs, I want to return a new dictionary where the key value pairs are reversed and all the non unique pair are removed from the new dictionary without modifying the original dictionary.

pls help :(

Input:

```
>>> invert({'one':1, 'two':2, 'uno':1, 'dos':2, 'three':3, 'un':1})
```

Expected result `{3: 'three'}`

This is my attempt at solving the problem:

```
inverted_dict = {}

for key,value in d.items(): #iterate throught a dict
    nonu = value
    if nonu in inverted_dict:
        del inverted_dict[nonu]
    else:
        inverted_dict[value] = key

return inverted_dict
```

It returns: `{3: 'three', 1: 'un'}`

Comment: It's worth noting that `nonu = value` is pointless and your code would be clearer if you removed it

Comment: BTW, welcome back to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to keep track of keys you've seen *other* that the inverted dict because when you delete those keys from the dict, it is not longer effective. This has the effect of only saving keys with odd number of occurrences. Here's one way using a set to keep track of what you've seen:

```
def invert(d):
    seen = set()
    ret = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        if v not in seen:
            seen.add(v)
            ret[v] = k   
        elif v in ret:
            del ret[v]
            
    return ret
    
invert({'one':1, 'two':2, 'uno':1, 'dos':2, 'three':3, 'un':1})
# {3: 'three'}
```

Here's how you might do it by counting using Python's built-in [Collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

def invert(d):
    counts = Counter(d.values())
    return {v:k for k, v in d.items() if counts[v] == 1}

invert({'one':1, 'two':2, 'uno':1, 'dos':2, 'three':3, 'un':1})
# {3: 'three'}
```